# IE 11 in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, internet-explorer-11

I have come across a web page today that states it only works in IE 11. However, I am currently running Windows 11, and when attempting to install IE 11 from Microsoft, it states that a newer version is already installed, but it does not show up in Features, or apps.

How can I get access to IE 11 in Windows 11?

Comment: @medic17 no, as per the answers provided in this question, there is a compatibility mode in Edge now that allows for certain extensions etc. that require the IE 11 environment to function. In the linked question, they do provide solutions, but this has now been updated.

Comment: @Ben the OP in that question specifically writes that they *don't* want   compatibility mode. Did  compatibility mode  solve your problem? If not I updated my answer with my solution and you can also check https://superuser.com/a/1746047/1070442 . I tested that answer and it still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said you can use Edge compatibility mode:
[image: Edge settings. Click reload in explorer mode]

You may need to enable this in Settings > apps > optional features internet explorer mode.

If this doesn't work you can try this small c# program:

```
// To hide the console windows change solution properties to "windows application"

namespace Main
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The SHDocVw object requires a refrence to COM object "Microsoft Internet Controls"
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new();
            object URL;

            if (args.Length >= 1)
            {
                URL = args[0];
            }
            else
            {
                URL = "http://www.google.com"; // home page
            }

            // Call the IE instance to open the specified URL 
            IE.Visible = true;
            IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
        }
    }
}
```

publish as a single `exe` and use it like you would with the regular internet explorer. It supports passing a web page as a command line argument for scripting purposes.

Full code available in my [repo](https://github.com/medic17/win11ie). Feel free to help out.

Answer (score 2):

Use Edge in Compatibility mode.   Edge Compatibility mode handles 90 to 95% of IE11 requirements.

That should work.

If not, contact the web page development support.

You cannot install IE11 in Windows 11 - not possible in any way.

You can also use an older machine.  I have IE11 working on a Windows 7 virtual machine. It may be a tad inconvenient but the virtual machine approach does work.

Remember that IE11 is being withdrawn and so actually Edge in Compatibility Mode may be your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides virtual machines with IE preinstalled for testing purposes free of charge. They can be downloaded [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). They can be downloaded for a variety of VM platforms. If you don't have a preferred one, I would suggest VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Open Internet Properties
3. Select the Programs Tab
4. Click Manage add-ons
5. Click Learn more about toolbars and extensions

An Internet Explorer 11 window will appear

Comment: Not in Windows 11.   Your post is for earlier operating systems.

Comment: Weird, works for me, I'm definitely running Windows 11